# What are some scenarios in which you need ASP.net Web API to consume a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I know that ASP.net web service supports only HTTP protocol and with WCF you have more options like TCP and Named pipes etc. Can you think of any scenarios in which one might have to consume a WCF service through an ASP.net Web API?

Comment: If you already have a wcf service running and available which is doing some complex operations and you do not want it to be available directly to your consumers, you can create a web API and call the wcf service to perform the complex tasks and let the consumers to use the web API. In web API you can put extra logic of validation and authorization of the incoming requests.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya cant the validation and authorization of requests be done in the WCF service? is that the only reason for using them together?

Comment: As I said if you do not want to expose the wcf service to your customers as it is, you can front it by web API. Wcf being and old technology it would be easier to write something new and eventually discard the old one rather than maintaining it. Also if wcf is not working with http protocol then not all the clients will be able to use it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It may have different answer based on the actual problem you are trying to solve. My answer is based on the information you provided and my experience.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hmm, makes sense. one more thing on your last line "Also if WCF is not working with HTTP protocol then not all the clients will be able to use it", will the web api still be able to communicate with WCF service if its not working with the HTTP protocol?

Comment: If the wcf service is available on tcp and web API and wcf are running on the same network, then web API can call wcf. There are other factors too in this integration to work.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for the clarification. if you want to post an answer to this question, I'll mark it.

Comment: Please find the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following would be one of them use case where you want to call wcf service from web API.

If you already have a wcf service running and available which is doing some complex operations and you do not want it to be available directly to your consumers, you can create a web API and call the wcf service to perform the complex tasks and let the consumers to use the web API. In web API you can put extra logic of validation and authorization of the incoming requests.

Wcf being an older technology it would be better to write something new and eventually replace wcf rather than maintaining it.

Also If the current wcf is setup is not available via http protocol then not all the clients can communicate with it. Web API has that edge over wcf service.

How web API would connect to wcf service? 
This depends on lot of factors such as network, deployment strategy, security etc.
But following would be one of the examples.

If the wcf service is available on tcp and web API and wcf are running on the same network, then web API can call wcf.

There may be a different answer to this question based on what exact problem you are trying to solve.

My answer is based on what information you have provided and the experience I gained by solving similar issue in real life.